# Google Workspace Marketplace SDK unexpectedly removing OAuth scopes from App Configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apps-marketplace

I have a *private* Drive app that uses the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK. It uses a service account that gets access to the necessary OAuth scopes after an admin has installed the app in the Marketplace. The list of OAuth scopes it should get access to can be configured in the App Configuration page of the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK.

It has happened more than twice now that Google unexpectedly removes the OAuth scope needed by the app  (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file) in the App Configuration and all that is left are the default userinfo.email and userinfo.profile scopes. This seems to occur whenever the add-on is uninstalled and then reinstalled in the Google Workspace Marketplace.
Is there a reason why Google would do this? Can this also happen for public Google Worskpace Marketplace add-ons?

It would be very unpractical as it means we would have to check regularly whether it has been removed and if it is removed before a customer installs it, the add-on won't work and will have to be reinstalled/configured with help.

Comment: Does anyone else have access to the app and might remove the scopes? Moreover, what kind of app do you have?

Comment: @ale13 only a few people have access and I am sure it wasn't someone accidentally removing scopes. It is a Drive App.

Comment: Do you have any possibility of checking the history of the scopes added/removed? Moreover, do you have any triggers that might update the project/the scopes?